# Regex to convert html-image to XML to avoid preloading

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, image

I am currently pulling an XML feed into a webapp through ajax. Obviously i like using jquery to parse it, like so:

```
$(source).find("item");
```

The problem with this is that everything is converted into nodes, including -tags. Considering this is some sort of RSS feed, and the feed contains complete articles (including image galleries), there are many img-tags. To prevent this, i would like to try and convert the img-tags to something like this:

before:

```
<img src="path_to_img.jpg" width="450" height="199" alt="alt description" title="image title" class="image_classes" />
```

after:

```
<image>
<src>path_to_img.jpg</src>
<alt>alt description</alt>
<title>image title</title>
<class>image_classes</class>
</image>
```

If anyone has better suggestions than using regexes, those are of course welcome too. But because it all has to be treated like text, I fear there are few, considering images start preloading when they are added to the DOM.

Comment: you cannot pull off such thing with just a regex i believe. you need some more structure in a function

Comment: When dealing with structured data, you should better use DOM or some parser than regexes to handle, add, remove, transform or convert nodes ... Or [XSL](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) which is just made for such transformations. It would be way much more safer and solid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not going to be very easy unless you can guarantee all those attributes will always be present, and always in quoted strings etc etc.

```
var html = '<img src="path_to_img.jpg" width="450" height="199" alt="alt description" title="image title" class="image_classes" />';
var regex = /<img .*?(src|alt|title|class)="([^"]*)" .*?(src|alt|title|class)="([^"]*)" .*?(src|alt|title|class)="([^"]*)" .*?(src|alt|title|class)="([^"]*)".*?\/?>/g;
var xmlTemplate = '<image><$1>$2</$1><$3>$4</$3><$5>$6</$5><$7>$8</$7></image>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​';
var xml = html.replace(regex, xmlTemplate);
```

If your source HTML is not as uniform, then you might have to use `.replace(regex, func)` instead of `.replace(regex, string)`.

As you have said the alt attribute may not be present, then you will need to use regex with a function, like this:

```
var html = '<img src="path_to_img.jpg" width="450" height="199" alt="alt description" title="image title" class="image_classes" />';
var regex = /<img .*?>/gi;
function getAttributeValue(tag, attribute)
{
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + attribute + '="([^"]*)"', 'i');
    var match = tag.match(regex);
    return '\t<' + attribute + '>' + (match ? match[1] : '') + '</' + attribute + '>\n';
}

var xml = html.replace(regex, function($0)
{
    var xml = '<image>\n';
    xml += getAttributeValue($0, 'src');
    xml += getAttributeValue($0, 'alt');
    xml += getAttributeValue($0, 'title');
    xml += getAttributeValue($0, 'class');
    xml += '</image>';
    return xml;
});
```

Comment: This one did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for just the first two attributes, src and alt:

```
HTMLstring.replace(new RegExp("<img src=\"([^\"]+)\".*alt=\"([^\"]+)\"","gm"), "<image><src>$1</src><alt>$2</alt></image>")
```

If you foresee that some attributes might be missing, you could use the `|` operator to manage all the alternatives or might go for a mixed approach where you extract a set of key-value pairs from the `img` tag then join them together with some js:

```
    $.each(HTMLstring.replace(/<img ([^ =]+)="([^"]+).*\/>/), function () {
        <do_what_you_need_with($1, $2)>
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast contribution! What happens in case, say, the alt-tag is missing? will i just have <alt></alt> then? (would be awesome if i did)

Comment: I used the solution above. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the alt tag being completely excluded from the xml if it is not present in the html then you can use this:

```
var regex = /\s+(src|alt|title|class)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/gi;
var res;
var xml = '<image>\n';
while ((res = regex.exec(html)) !== null) {
    xml += "\t<" + res[1] + ">" + res[2] + "</" + res[1] + ">\n";
}
xml += "</image>";
```